# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function error when I connect Redux to the project

Tags: reactjs, redux

I see this problem the first time and any google can't help me(
I don't understand what it is, long time I was doing the same and all was good, can't understand anything

My code looks:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./style/main.scss";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducers from "./reducers/index";
import { createStore } from "redux/es/redux";

const store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

My error looks:

```
index.js:1375 The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:
    in Provider (at index.js:12)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

AND ONE MORE ERROR:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Provider (Provider.js:10)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:13922)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:14376)
....
```

MY package-json:

```
{
  "name": "interview-question",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^1.28.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.4",
    "react-spinners": "^0.6.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

REDUCER index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import data from "./data";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  data
});

export default reducers;
```

data.js :

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  time: undefined,
  products: undefined
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "PRODUCTS_WAS_RECIEVED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        products: payload
      };
    }
    case "TIME_WAS_RECIEVED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        time: payload
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Maybe someone knows how to fix it? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post your reducers?

Comment: I'm not sure about the import `redux/es/redux`, haven't seen it before, could it be a problem ?

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington let's see now please

Comment: Could it be that `index.js` should be `index.jsx`? This depends on the configuration but could be.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a later version of `react` and `react-dom`. Better still use the following in your `package.json`:

```
"react": "next",
"react-dom": "next"
```

Then update dependencies with `yarn upgrade` or `npm update`.